# Вопрос: как сделать игру/программу с загружаемым кешем

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, kotlin

Возможно ли сделать такое, что:
на андроид или iOS будет установлено приложение, которое в зависимости от того, появилась ли новая версия, будет закачивать кеш и использовать его, но не будет обновлять саму программу?

Я такое видел уже во многих играх на мобильном устройстве, когда сама программа не обновляется, а всего лишь докачиваются данные, необходимые для работы обновления.

Что это такое, как это работает, ссылки на литературу, буду рад любой информации!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать такое можно. Можно очень по разному.

1. Код не меняется, скачиваются только файлы. Например - картинки, звуки, которе используются в коде.
2. Не знаю про iOS, но в андроид можно настроить разбиение приложения на части, с их динамической подгрузкой по требованию. Это не избавляет от необходимости перезаливать код в магазин, но сокращает изначальный размер установочного файла.
3. Не знаю про iOS, но в Android (скорее даже просто в Java), можно скомпилированный код загрузить и использовать в программе на этапе исполнени. Например класс экрана загрузить и отобразить. Однако это жуткая дыра в безопасности и в магазин такое приложение корпорация зла не пустит.